# interval$\Rightarrow$ connected, proof

Tags: general-topology

If i suppose that $I$ is an interval but it is not connected,i.e there existe two open sets on $I$: $U,V$ such that $I=U\cup V$ et $U\cap V=\emptyset$

Let $x\in U$ and $y\in V$ (for example $x<y$) and let $B_x=\{z\in U, [x,z]\subset U\}$

Then $B_x$ is bounded  by y .

My question is why $B_x$ is bounded by $y$ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wrong in your assumptions. Saying that $I$ is not connected means there exist two open sets $U$ and $V$ such that

- $I\subseteq U\cup V$
- $(U\cap I)\cap(V\cap I)=\emptyset$
- $U\cap I\ne\emptyset$ and $V\cap I\ne\emptyset$

Or you have to say that $U$ and $V$ are open sets in $I$ (with the relative topology).

Fix $x\in U\cap I$ and $y\in V\cap I$. It's not restrictive to assume $x<y$ (otherwise exchange the roles of $U$ and $V$).

Then $B_x=\{z\in I:[x,z]\subseteq U\}$ is bounded by $y$, because if $z\in B_x$ and $z>y$, then $[x,z]\subseteq U$ implies $y\in [x,z]$ and so $y\in U$: this is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, after that theu say let $M=\sup B_x$ then $x\leq H\leq y$, As $I$ is an interval $M\in I$ moreover $B_x\subset U\subset I \Rightarrow M\in \overline{B_x}\subset \overline{U}$ but $U=C_{I}V$ closed $\Rightarrow M\in U$ As $U$ is open $\exists \varepsilon>0, ]M-\varepsilon,M+\varepsilon[\subset U$ the conclusion follows from the definition of sup. I don't understand this part of proof

Comment: Please why $U=C_{I}V$ ? thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou What's $C_IV$? And what does this have to do with the proof I presented?

Comment: ah sorry , there is no relation with your answer , i just want to know why U and V are open and closed in I sorry

Comment: @Vrouvrou Suppose $M=\sup B_x$; then $x\le M\le y$ and $M\in I$. On the one hand, $M$ belongs to the closure of $B_x$ in $I$ (the supremum always belongs to the closure); since $B_x\subset U$, we have that $M$ belongs to the closure in $I$ of $U\cap I$, which however is closed being the complement of $V\cap I$, which is open (in $I$).

Comment: yes thank you so $M\in U$ but U is open so there exist $\varepsilon>0,$  $M\in ]M-\varepsilon,M+\varepsilon[\subset U,$ so there exist $M+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\in U$, but please to obtain that $M+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \in B_x$, we must have that $[x,\frac{\varepsilon}{2}]\subset U$, why this is possible please ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou By definition, $[x,M+\varepsilon/2]\subseteq U$, so $M+\varepsilon\in B_x$, which is absurd.

Comment: we just have that $x\in U$ and $M+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\in U$ but U is not an interval so why $[x,\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+M]\subset U$

Comment: @Vrouvrou Please! $(M-\varepsilon,M+\varepsilon)\subseteq U$; on the other hand, ***by definition of supremum***, there exists $z\in B_x$ such that $M-\varepsilon<z\le M$. So $[x,z]\subseteq U$; therefore $[x,z]\cup(M-\varepsilon,M+\varepsilon/2]\subseteq U$. What's that union? Of course it contains $[x,M+\varepsilon/2]$.

Comment: OHHHH ye M is the suppremum thank you very much

Comment: please when we say that there is a contradiction with the fact that $M=\sup B_x$ is this imply that $U=\emptyset$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Non emptyness of $B_x$ is contradictory. So $B_x=\emptyset$, which contradicts $x\in U$. Therefore no element of $I$ can belong to $U$, hence $U\cap I=\emptyset$. You cannot prove $U=\emptyset$, but you just need $U\cap I=\emptyset$.

Comment: In my proof i take $U\subset I$ open in $I$ then $U\cap I=U $,  and if $B_x=\emptyset$ we just have that $B_x\subset U $ where $B_x=\{z\in U, [x,z]\subset U\}$ so why $U\cap A=\emptyset$ please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34368/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-egreg).

Comment: are you there please

Answer (score 2):

Because if $z\geq y$, then $y\in [x,z]$, this means that $[x,z]$ cannot be a subset of $U$

(because it contains at least one element, $y$, from $V$, and since $y\in V$, we know that $y\notin U$).

---

For part two, you show that there exists such an $\epsilon$ that $(M-\epsilon, M+\epsilon)$ is a subset of $U$. This means that $M$ is not the upper bound of $B_x$, because $[x,M+\epsilon)$ is a subset of $U$, so, for example, $M+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is in $B_x$ (because $[x,M+\frac\epsilon2] \subset [x, M+\epsilon)\subset U$).

Comment: Thank you, after that theu say let $M=\sup B_x$ then $x\leq H\leq y$, As $I$ is an interval $M\in I$ moreover $B_x\subset U\subset I \Rightarrow M\in \overline{B_x}\subset \overline{U}$ but $U=C_{I}V$ closed $\Rightarrow M\in U$ As $U$ is open $\exists \varepsilon>0, ]M-\varepsilon,M+\varepsilon[\subset U$ the conclusion follows from the definition of sup. I don't understand this part of proof

Comment: @Vrouvrou What's $H$ in $x\leq H\leq y$? Also, rather than in a comment, post what you just posted as an edit to your question, making it clear that that's part two of your question.

Comment: @Vrouvrou See the edit to my answer for part two.

Comment: it is not $H$ sorry it is $M$, can you explain me the part "moreover $B_x\subset U\subset I \Rightarrow M\in \overline{B_x}\subset \overline{U}$..."

Comment: please why the fact that $B_x\subset U\subset I$ impliese that $M\in \overline{B_x}\subset \overline{U}$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou The supremum of every set is also an element of the closure of the set. This follows, more or less, from the definition of closures.

Comment: @Vrouvrou If I understand, then $C_IV$ simply means the **complement** of $V$ (with regards to $I$), in other words, $U=I\setminus V$, which is obvious from the fact that $V\cup U=I$ and $V\cap U=\emptyset.$

Comment: @Vrouvrou take 10 minutes of actual work before you ask questions. I refuse to hold your hand every step of the way, because neither of us gains anything from that.

Comment: please the contradiction gives that $B_x=\emptyset$ or $U=\emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $B_{x}$ were *not* bounded by $y$, i.e., there is some $z$ such that $y \leq z$ and $[x,z] \subset U$.  Then since $y \in [x,z]$, we have $y \in U$, which contradicts that $y \in V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you, after that theu say let $M=\sup B_x$ then $x\leq H\leq y$, As $I$ is an interval $M\in I$ moreover $B_x\subset U\subset I \Rightarrow M\in \overline{B_x}\subset \overline{U}$ but $U=C_{I}V$ closed $\Rightarrow M\in U$ As $U$ is open $\exists \varepsilon>0, ]M-\varepsilon,M+\varepsilon[\subset U$ the conclusion follows from the definition of sup. I don't understand this part of proof